# Run script before installing packages with nodeLinker set to node-modules

Tags: yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2, yarn-v2

I have to run a script (from my `package.json` file) before I run `yarn install`. The script sets up the configuration for a private package. In my `.yarnrc.yml`, I have `nodeLinker: node-modules` (and I want to keep it that way because I get other errors if I remove it).

The problem is that when I run `yarn run myscript` I have the following error:

```
Usage Error: Couldn't find the node_modules state file - running an install might help (findPackageLocation)

$ yarn run [--inspect] [--inspect-brk] [-T,--top-level] [-B,--binaries-only] <scriptName> ...
```

But I can't run `install` before the script since I have private packages that need the script before it gets installed.

I just switched from NPM to Yarn 3.2.0. With NPM, I was able to run the script before installing packages.